# Sheet growing enormously due to real-time data updates

Tags: vba, excel, real-time

I have electrical power reading equipment that can update the power changes from a server every second on to an Excel sheet. I am running a Java program which can access this real-time data for my scheduling purposes but I need only the last updated data when I access Excel. The Excel sheet is growing enormously due to the data updating every second.

Is there any way by which I can program, within the Excel sheet or with help of any tool, to delete all old data beyond a particular limit, all the while saving the most recent ten or so last updated readings (I don't want to be returned null at any time when my program tries to access the last row of data - so there should always be a reading in Excel)?

Comment: What is the format of the data? Is it one row per update (i.e. per second) or a random number of rows? Is there a timestamp within each row?

Comment: @pnuts : I cannot ask modify the equipment software that writes into the excel...

Comment: @ A.S.H : yes its one row per update which is every second.

Answer (score 1):

This bit of code will keep the last 10 rows.
The assumption is that it will kick in each time the worksheet changes.

the code goes into the worksheet module.

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    KeepLst10Rws
End Sub



Sub KeepLst10Rws()
    Dim rws As Long
    rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If rws > 10 Then
        Rows("1:" & (rws - 10)).Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So this would be the answer?